# Using python hashmap for counting elements

Tags: python, hashmap

When i need to count elements of different type , i find myself writing something like:

```
if k not in removed:
    removed[k] = 0
removed[k] = removed[k] + 1
```

Sometimes i do the same thing with a new empty list that will grow over time.
The above code works fine, but it feels like there is a better way of writing it.
Is there?

Comment: I think you might be looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :) This site is for code that doesn't work. `CodeReview` is for code that works, but you would like to try and make better. :)

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: You can make that slightly neater by using a [defauldict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of a plain dict. There's also a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which has some powerful methods, but it runs a little slower, so if speed's an issue use defaultdict, unless you want to use those Counter methods.

Comment: Thanks guys that Counters and defaultdict is what i'm looking for. Next time i'l use codereview (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to defaultdict/Counter mentioned in comments, you can also have a default value returned from a failed `get`. This allows you to set the initial count to 0 if the key lookup fails and immediately increment by 1, or increment by 1 each time the key is found as you loop through.

```
vehicles = ['car', 'bike', 'truck', 'car', 'truck', 'truck']

my_dict = {}
for k in vehicles:
    my_dict[k] = my_dict.get(k, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
countdict = dict()
for k in inputlist:
    if k not in countdict.keys():
        countdict[k] = inputlist.count(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the `Counter` is for!
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter